# Which one is more fast in searching "ordered arraylist" or "BST"?

Tags: java, arraylist, binary-search-tree

When BST ordered it works fine, but in some cases it can be unbalanced. What happens in these cases, is BST still efficient?
We can directly access the n<sup>th</sup> element in the ArrayList, so is it more efficient than BST or not?

Comment: If you search the ordered `ArrayList` with a binary search it is as fast as the best case of the BST. Because that's what it is. If you search with a linear search, it isn't.

Comment: You may find this video about the performance of different datastructures interesting.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo

Comment: @EJP I doubt this is about linear search since there would be no point in mentioning that the arraylist is ordered then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted arrays are always fastest for searching.
Binary search trees consume more memory and may require more levels of indirection, which hurts performance and increases the chance of cache misses.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for a value in a sorted array is a bit faster although it has the same asymptotic bound. If you're searching for a the nth element sorted arrays are way faster though. In Java things like TreeSet and TreeMap are based on Red-Black trees which are self balancing without affecting the running time. (They have a maximum depth of 2log(n) instead of log(n) as a perfectly balanced tree.)